# How do I pick which CSS class is displayed on page load using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image version and a text version of my site logo in the following HTML tags. I want to pick which one to show based on where in the page I am vertically and the screen width.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" id="top-logo" href="#top"><img src="display_board.png" alt="Page Title"></a>
<a class="navbar-brand scroll" id="bottom-logo" href="#top">Page Title</a>
```

The following script functions correctly for screen resizing and scrolls once the page is loaded. When the site is loaded on mobile, **the image logo appears first when viewing on mobile before quickly updating to the text logo**, since the script file is loaded at end of the HTML file.

```
var method_update_nav = function() {
  var buffer = 200;
  var horizontal_switch_point = 1200;
  var vertical_switch_point = $('.carousel-indicators').offset().top - buffer;
  var window_top = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());

  if ($(window).width() <= horizontal_switch_point || window_top >= vertical_switch_point) {
    $('nav').removeClass('top');
    $('nav').addClass('bottom');
    $('#top-logo').hide();
    $('#bottom-logo').show();
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('bottom');
    $('nav').addClass('top');
    $('#top-logo').show();
    $('#bottom-logo').hide();
  }
};

var main = function() {
  /* UPDATE NAV */
  method_update_nav();
  $(window).resize(method_update_nav);
  $(window).scroll(method_update_nav);
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Loading the script in the HTML `<header>` causes the script to not function, since the classes the JQuery is referencing haven't been defined in HTML tags yet.

Is there a way to pick the correct class to show as the page loads, but after the classes have been defined in the HTML tags?

Comment: Your question is missing some details, please take time to revise it. My solution seems to solve a part of your problem.

Comment: It has been revised.

Comment: The code you have should work with th edit to use `$(document).ready`.

Comment: It works except for loading on a scroll position or screen width that should use the text logo. The image logo flickers first before the text logo finally appears. I was hoping to get rid of this flicker.

Answer (score 1):

> Loading the script in the HTML `<header>` causes the script to not function, since the classes the JQuery is referencing haven't been defined in HTML tags yet.

You say it yourself!

So you are using jQuery and I hope you know that you must place the script which references to HTML elements at the bottom of the page in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //script will now get the values because the HTML in now Loaded
})
```

I advise you to read some tutorials on the web.